# extjs getChangedData() doesn't include last edited record

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I have a grid where cellediting plugin is in place, I am posting the data through direct event.

I have a save button just below the grid which sends the direct event.

All works well barring following scenario:

**If I press save button while editing a row, the getChangedData doesn't consider that row dirty.**

If I put an alert in between (in the before event), it works as expected but thats not an option. I tried all possible hacks, like sending the onblur event of the active element, showing waitmsg, programmatically setting focus somewhere else but nothing helps.

Looking for help.

Cheers,

Avinash

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this script on save button handler.

```
//get the current selected row of your grid
var selectedRecord = gridpanel.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
var selectedRow = gridpanel.store.indexOf(selectedRecord);

//get the index of selected row
var idx = selectedRow <= -1 ? (gridpanel.store.getCount() - 1) : selectedRow;


gridpanel.plugins[0].startEditByPosition({
                          row: idx, 
                          column: columnNumberWithEditor}); 

//proceeed to saving data
```

[startEditByPosition](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-method-startEditByPosition) will fire the [edit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-edit) event.

Make sure also to handle the `edit` event on your cellEditing plugin.

```
listeners : {
    'edit' : function(editor, e) {
        e.record.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried it but it didn't work, I would like to explain further. The scenario is, I am in a column editor and instead of clicking outside of the editor to mark the record dirty, I directly click on the save button. Now when I check at the server side I don't get the record which was being edited before jumping to save button.

Comment: hmm.. have you tried to listen to the cellEditing `edit` event? please see my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work as well. It looks like it is by design.

Comment: did you get a solution to this;as we face a nearly similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to edit my grid in IE7 (not a problem with Chrome).

I think the problem is that my save button event handler gets called BEFORE the onBlur event can tell the the edit cell to complete its edit and put its value in the store.

What I did to work around this was:

(1) Defining my panel grid editor separately.

```
  var myPanelGridEditor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit: 1
  });
```

(2) Define my panel grid that includes my panel grid editor in the plugins.

```
  var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: 'myPanelGrid', store: myStore, viewConfig: {markDirty: false},
    columnLines: true,
    columns: [
      {header: 'HE01', dataIndex: 'vp01', sortable: false, maxWidth: 40, field: {xtype: 'numberfield', minValue: 0, hideTrigger: true, decimalPrecision: 4  }},
      {header: 'HE02', dataIndex: 'vp02', sortable: false, maxWidth: 40, field: {xtype: 'numberfield', minValue: 0, hideTrigger: true, decimalPrecision: 4  }}
    ],
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.RowModel', {mode: 'SINGLE'}),
    plugins: [myPanelGridEditor],
    height: 73, width: 1010, margin: '0 0 12 30'
  });
```

(3) Add a call to completeEdit() in my save button event handler

```
{
  text: 'Save',
  formBind: true,
  id: 'saveButton',
  handler: function () {
    myPanelGridEditor.completeEdit();          
    ...
  }
}
```

In theory you should be able to call

```
myGridPanel.editingPlugin.completeEdit();
```

in your save handler but in Ext JS 3.3.1 that property was null.